# Uncountable subset $S$ of $(0,1) \implies (0,1)$ has subinterval of limit points of $S$?

Tags: real-analysis

If $S$ is an uncountable subset of $(0,1)$, is there an interval $(a,b) \subseteq (0,1)$ such that every point in $(a,b)$ is a limit point of $S$?

Comment: No.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Someone down-voted the question. Why? If no comment explains it, then it is more reasonable to assume it's because the down-voter suspects the poster of an affair with his wife than to suspect any reason that makes sense within the appropriate usages of this forum. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the [Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) is a well known counter example to this.